# Create custom call out for mapbox in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I am using map box sdk  for my application to get customized map. I able to change color of land, sea, street,etc. But I also have to make callout customized as show in image below.  The small rectangle is closed callout the big rectangle is when call out pop is up.[image]

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this problem ?
Documentation explains how to change title, image and accessory. Not the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/callout-accessory-view/) contains an example of how to do this.

You have to implement the following delegate method and return your custom marker.

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
```

Comment: This is only for a custom accessory, not how to replace the whole callout with a custom view.  I am trying to figure this out too!

Comment: The example returns an RMMarker, but you can return you own implementation of an RMMapLayer that looks however you like.

Comment: Does this RMMapLayer object this delegate method returns describe the marker that appears on the map or the bubble that appears when you touch the marker?

Comment: You first add a marker annotation. When you get the tap event for the marker you can remove it and add your callout annotation. In this method you return the view for an annotation.

Comment: Interesting, have you managed to make this work, I wonder if you maybe have some code you can share?  I went digging into the SDK source and it seems that the bubble is drawn by the SMCallOutView by selectAnnotation:(RMAnnotation*)anAnnotation animated:(BOOL)animated in RMMapView.m It seems the left and right accessory views and NSString title are hard wired, without changing the SMCallOutView code and also the RMMapView I think you are stuck with having a short line of text only in the middle.